# Need to refresh page before changing element style

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to customize a shop cart with jQuery ajax validation, function in my server side are running smooth so far, my real problem is after adding the item in the cart. The Item name should be changing the color to indicate that the item is already selected, but it needs to manually refresh the page to start changing the color of the item name.

Here's the picture below:

[image]

After I click the '+' button, here's the output:

[image]

As you can see in the picture I've encircle the selected item, that should be changing the color after selecting the item.

Please see the code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".form-item").submit(function(e){
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
    button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text 

    $.ajax({ //make ajax request to cart_process.php
        url: "cart_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
        data: form_data
    }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
        $("#cart-info").html(data.items); //total items in cart-info element
        button_content.html('+'); //reset button text to original text
        alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user

    if($(".shopping-cart-box").css("display") == "block"){ //if cart box is still visible
        loadinc(); //trigger to update data

    }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
    });

    //Show Items in Cart
    function loadinc(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".shopping-cart-box").show(); //display cart box              
        $("#shopping-cart-results" ).load( "cart_process.php", {"load_cart":"1"}); //Make ajax request using jQuery Load() & update results

        });
    }
    loadinc();

});
```

And here's the HTML File

```
<?php
//List products from database
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbldata where category = 'SALAD'");
if (!$results){
    printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli_conn->error);
    exit;
}


//Display fetched records as you please
$products_list =  '<ul class="products-wrp">';

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= '
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>'.

(in_array($row["name"],array_column($_SESSION["products"],'name')) ? '<span style="color:#b91e2d;">'.$row["name"].'</span>' :  $row["name"])

.'</h4>

<div>Price : '.$currency.' '.$row["price"].'<div>
<div class="item-box">


    <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    </div>      

    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="'.$row["product_code"].'">
    <button type="submit">+</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
';

}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';

echo $products_list;
?>
```

Comment: So change the applied CSS where you do `alert("Item added to Cart!");`

Comment: in your done - success function add your css to change the color of selected item, you are missing your styling there

Comment: hi @karthik my styling are located in my html file, I've include a shorthanded if statement there to check the variable in array is selected.

Comment: Your life would be so much easier with a framework like Vue, just a suggestion

Comment: I'm newbie sir, need to study more before Im advancing into different framework:(

Answer (score 1):

You forgot this line:

```
.css('color', '#b91e2d');
```

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
        var title = $(this).closest('span');
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
        button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text 

        $.ajax({ //make ajax request to cart_process.php
            url: "cart_process.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json", //expect json value from server
            data: form_data
        }).done(function(data){ //on Ajax success
            $("#cart-info").html(data.items); //total items in cart-info element
            button_content.html('+'); //reset button text to original text
            alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
            title.css('color','#b91e2d');

            if($(".shopping-cart-box").css("display") == "block"){ //if cart box is still visible
                loadinc(); //trigger to update data
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //Show Items in Cart
    function loadinc(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".shopping-cart-box").show(); //display cart box              
            $("#shopping-cart-results" ).load( "cart_process.php", {"load_cart":"1"}); //Make ajax request using jQuery Load() & update results
        });
    }
    loadinc();
});
```

And also, your item should be:

```
$products_list .= '
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4><span'.

(in_array($row["name"],array_column($_SESSION["products"],'name')) ? ' style="color:#b91e2d;" :  "")

. '>' . $row["name"] . '</span></h4>'...etc.
```

Comment: it's not triggering sir, It's also needs to refresh before changing the color

Comment: You need to catch the item you are clicking and save it into a variable. I'll post an edit with the full code.

Comment: its not working sir. I tried to put a class name in my span and call it after after alert fucntion, but nothings change it needs to refresh the page to change the color of the name

(in_array($row["name"],array_column($_SESSION["products"],'name')) ? '<span class="testing" style="color:#b91e2d;">'.$row["name"].'</span>' :  $row["name"])

Comment: That's because you are printing the "<span>" only if the product is selected. So when it's not (remember that ajax runs AFTER your PHP loads) there's no span there to change the style. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: its not working sir. need to refresh the page  to work.

Comment: did i miss something here? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for helping.

I should need to put

```
window.location.reload();
```

after aler function.

Thanks guys. :D

Comment: A major reason for using AJAX is to _avoid_ doing a page reload.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is wrong I'm going for the answer of @NiMusco, my bad.